# JavaScript in Netbeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans, intellisense, netbeans-7, netbeans-7.1

I am using **Netbeans 7.1**. I use Netbeans to write JavaScript inside HTML and in JS files. The case is, it seems like Netbeans's IntelliSense doesn't have all methods and variables JavaScript has. For an example, if I type `navigator` and place the dot operator (`navigator.`), Intellisense doesn't show the `cookieEnabled` boolean property. This is just a one example, but I have found many. Why is this so? Is there a way to fix it? Please help!

Comment: Nice one! But I guess you can post this as a bug to Netbeans Bug Tracker. What say? The link to bug tracker is http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html.

Comment: Sure... :) Lets update it here too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans? Really? You don't need an super-IDE for Javascript. With a text editor as Sublimetext and a browser with Javascript console you can do it all :)